# WMI win32_volume DirtyBitSet information is not showing up at every volume

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, system.management

I am trying to find out if there are **volumes** on my system that **are flagged as dirty**. In my approach I requested the information from the **Win32_Volume class** but **not every drive contains information about the state of "DirtyBitSet".** Am I overlooking something? Unfortunately using the fsutil dirty query command via the command line is not an option since the output is in the respective system language. Thank you in advance.

```
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"] ?? "unknown");
                Console.WriteLine("DriveLetter: {0}", queryObj["DriveLetter"] ?? "unknown");
                Console.WriteLine("DirtyBitSet: {0}", queryObj["DirtyBitSet"] ?? "unknown");    //this one is inconsistent
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCeZv.png)

Comment: Does `fsutil` return the same data?

Comment: fsutil gives the correct information about every volume regarding the dirty bit but unfortunately the Win32_Volume class is not.